# Get list of start and end of months between 2 dates with moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have 2 dates like this

`2018-01-01` and `2019-01-01`

I want to return a list of all months between those 2 dates but get both the start of the month and the end in the list like this

```
 2018-01-01 - 2018-01-31
 2018-02-01 - 2018-02-28
 2018-03-01 - 2018-03-31
```

and so on for all months between the 2 dates. How would I do this with Moment JS?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @eramit2010 I have looked and found solutions to getting a singular date for each month but not both. Not quite sure where to start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```
var start = moment('2018-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
var end = moment('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')

while (start < end) {
  console.log(start.startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
  console.log(start.endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
  start.add(1, 'month')
}
```

As other users have pointed out `moment`'s objects mutate when you use methods like `startOf` and `endOf`, so you should consider cloning them like this:

```
var startOfMonth = start.clone().startOf('month')
// ... and so on
```

Comment: Seems simple enough, wasn't quite sure where to start with this one but this seems to make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just a small runnable sample. Be careful with moment.js: moments mutate!

I hope this will help you!

```js
const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
const start = moment('2018-01-01', format), end = moment('2019-01-01', format);
const result = [];
while(start.isBefore(end)) {
  result.push({
    start: start.startOf('month').format(format), 
    end: start.endOf('month').format(format)
  });
  start.add(1, 'month');
} 

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If interested in using [`moment-range` plugin](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range#snapto), use `range.by` to get ranges.

```js
window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);

var dateformat = "DD/MM/YYYY", start = moment("01/01/2018",dateformat), end = moment("01/12/2018",dateformat);

var range = moment.range(start,end);
var result = Array.from(range.by("month")).map(function(val){
    return [val.startOf("month").format(dateformat),val.endOf("month").format(dateformat)];
})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-range/4.0.1/moment-range.js"></script>
```